# Complex headers via Display Tag in struts2

Tags: struts2

I have to create a table using display:table tag, whose structure is like this

```
 <display:table name="ReportList" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
    <display:column property="claimType" title="Claim Type"  sortable="true" />
    <display:column property="claimno" title="Claim Number"  sortable="true"  />
    <display:column property="billStatus" title="Bill Status"  sortable="true" />
    <display:column property="transNo" title="Transaction Number"  sortable="true"/>
</display:table>
```

Now It is Display like this

|-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Claim Type |Claim No.|Bill Status | Transaction Number |
|---------------|-------------|--------------|----------------------------|
|---------------|-------------|--------------|----------------------------|

Now i want to display this table like this

|-----------Claim----------|---------------Bill--------------------|
|--- Type---- |-----No.----| Status | Transaction Number |
|---------------|-------------|----------|----------------------------|
|---------------|-------------|----------|----------------------------|

I am new in struts2 
Any one know how to do this please give me the details solution

Comment: the detailed solution would be removing a dysplay tag and build the table manually or using some other widgets that generate a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an struts 2 issue.

You are using `display:tag` to create the main table.

Now, you can wrap the generated table in a table itself. Of course you must set the `width` of some elements

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Name</th>
    <th colspan="2">Family name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <display:table/>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can use also use jQuery (or plain javascript) to do some tricks if the table does not match your requirement (on the client side)

I suggest you resend your question and ask for a jQuery solution.

Comment: I am not using jquery. There is Table display using <display:table> tag. I want to add  complex header. If it is not possible using display tag please tell me how to do this using jquery

Comment: It is possible. Please attention the display:tag generates the main table, you want to decorate it with another header, you must use more HTML around _display:table_

Comment: I was try this Simple table but it will shows table inside another table. Its not looking proper

Comment: @Rohini of course it will not look proper its an example, as I said this is the approach which you can follow and you need to change the HTML according to your generated table.

Comment: @Rohini your welcome, By the way Its good idea to post some part of your css and jsp which may help others :)

Comment: I have added the Changed Css